# passing command line arguments to a specific **class** in a non-executable jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, arguments

Some context:
I am creating a Java project in Eclipse (only used Eclipse for a week). I picked up Java after a 13 year hiatus because I had to convert files from IBM EBCDIC 5035  & 935 to UTF-16. the standalone classes (two classes in all) work great within Eclipse.
Each class has two parameters - source file+location and target file+location
Each class will convert about a dozen files every night.

So now I have to automate the solution and deploy it. I used Eclipse to create a regular jar (NOT a runnable jar) so that I could call each class separately without creating a "manager" class.

On the command prompt when I run the following command:

**java -jar test.jar ConvFileCP_5035_To_UTF16 \\\\usanofp03\\Informatica\\Dev\\OutputFiles\\JDEJapanCustomer_CP939.txt \\\\usanofp03\\Informatica\\Dev\\OutputFiles\\JDEJapanCustomer.txt**

The output (confirmed with system.out...) surprised me because 
args[0] = ConvFileCP_5035_To_UTF16 (**the class name!**) and
args[1] = \\\\usanofp03\\Informatica\\Dev\\OutputFiles\\JDEJapanCustomer_CP939.txt

I flipped to using args[1] and args[2] and the program worked **but I wanted to know why this is happening and what is the right thing to do here**

help would be appreciated!
Thanks,

Comment: I think [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) should give you the answer.  It describes how to use the `-jar` option, and it looks like you're not supposed to give it another class name.  (Never tried this myself so I can't give you any other advice.)

Comment: I don't know what you are calling an "executable jar"; there is no such thing. Do you mean a `Main-Class` entry in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`?

Comment: from what I understand - when you create a runnable jar you need to specify the MAIN (entry) class in the MANIFEST. In Eclipse there is an option to create simply a jar file (non-executable is a misnomer on my part). This is what I have used. I want to be able to call classes within a jar without having to use the Main-Class entry which is what I am doing.

Comment: Then don't use `-jar`, since it expects `Main-Class`. Add the jar to your classpath and call `java name.of.MainClass <args here>`.

Answer (score 2):

**NB: I realise that this is an old question, but it does deserve an answer.**

While the questioner said that they *“used Eclipse to create a regular jar (NOT a runnable jar)”*, it looks like Eclipse may have actually specified one of their classes to be the main class in the JAR, which explains the output they experienced, i.e. `args[0]` holding the name of the class they intended to run.

The `-jar` option instructs `java` to "run" the given JAR, which actually causes `java` to look in the manifest, located inside the given JAR, for a line that specifies the main class. When a JAR is run, any further arguments are passed to the manifest-specified main class.

Following on from what *@fge* said, it looks like the questioner’s experience may have been the result of running an accidentally-made-runnable JAR that should have instead been used as a library, specified with the `-classpath` option, when invoking `java` and supplying the intended class.

For further investigation, see the following example.

Using the following class, which enumerates the command-line arguments it receives, we can demonstrate how the different `java` invocations behave:

```java
public class JarTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.println(i + ": " + args[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Compiling this class as normal (i.e. `javac JarTest.java`), we can run it in the usual way and supply some command-line arguments to see how it behaves:

```sh
~/temp/jar-test$ java JarTest arg1 arg2
0: arg1
1: arg2
```

The following command will package this class into a basic JAR:

```
~/temp/jar-test$ jar cf jar-test.jar JarTest.class
```

The last section of the [Running JAR-Packaged Software](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html) chapter of The Java Tutorials, headed “JAR Files as Applications”, explains that the only way to directly *“run a JAR packaged application”* is with the `-jar` option like in the following:

```
~/temp/jar-test$ java -jar jar-test.jar
no main manifest attribute, in jar-test.jar
```

However, as we can see above, this doesn’t work so easily. Notice here also that even explicitly specifying the intended main class doesn’t help:

```
~/temp/jar-test$ java -jar jar-test.jar JarTest arg1 arg2
no main manifest attribute, in jar-test.jar
```

As we will see below, this is because anything after the specified JAR becomes the command-line arguments for the main class, if one is found, thus it is effectively ignored by the `java` command itself. Of course, in the above case, those arguments aren’t actually passed to anything because `java` doesn’t yet know to which class it should pass them.

In order to actually run a JAR, the `java` command needs to know which class is the application’s entry point (i.e. the class with the main method) and this is specified in the JAR’s manifest via the `Main-Class` header. Without specifying the main class, we see the above error. The [Setting an Application's Entry Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) chapter of The Java Tutorials describes how to specify the main class in the JAR’s manifest. Following these instructions, we create `manifest.txt` with the following contents (including a final newline character):

```
Main-Class: JarTest
```

Re-create the JAR and include the manifest (see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html) for further details on the jar command):

```
~/temp/jar-test$ jar cfm jar-test.jar manifest.txt JarTest.class
```

Now we can try to run our new JAR:

```
~/temp/jar-test$ java -jar jar-test.jar JarTest arg1 arg2
0: JarTest
1: arg1
2: arg2
```

As we can see, our JAR now runs successfully and the output is similar to the questioner’s curious output. When running a JAR that specifies the main class via the included manifest, there is no need to specify the intended class, indeed if we do, that string is passed to the main class as `args[0]`.

In order to achieve the desired outcome, we should instead run our program by adding the JAR to the classpath (the easiest way being via either the `-classpath` or `-cp` options) and specify the class to run:

```
~/temp/jar-test$ java -cp jar-test.jar JarTest arg1 arg2
0: arg1
1: arg2
```

If we compare this with the previous command, the only difference is that then we used the `-jar` option, whereas now we've used the `-cp` option and achieved what was likely the questioner’s intention.

It might be worth noting here that the above (`-cp`) method would work with either a basic JAR (i.e. one without a manifest-specified main class) or a runnable JAR, because we are now simply telling `java` to look within the given JAR for the specified class.

Comment: This is a great answer. Would you know if there is a way to avoid specifying JarTest while passing arguments and have it be the default class accepting args? eg. java -cp jar-test.jar arg1 arg2 but arg1 and arg2 are passed to JarTest by default.